# Load Data Local infie query working in mysql shell but not working in python

Tags: python, mysql, loaddata

When I use the load data local infile query manually in mysql, it is working fine. But when I execute it in python, it is not inserting any rows in my table. Sometimes, the last 10 records in the file are not loading into the table.

the following command works in mysql shell anytime:

```sql
LOAD data local infile 'file_log.txt'
INTO TABLE mytable fields terminated by ',';
```

in python:

```py
q="load data local infile 'file_log.txt' into table mytable fields terminated by ',';"

cur.execute(q)
```

This is an axample for the dummy text file I use (only the first line). All of the lines are similar to this line. Each row is in one line of the text file.

> A1B12C0032D,1234567890123@23a1,a1fai237hfsibiabEISN,sujay,daggubati,abc defgh st, abc, AB, 12345-67890, 123456789, sujaydaggubati1@gmail.com, 83, 79,31,19,41,62,92,11,0,81

Table definition:
Contains 21 Columns of type varchar(60)
(Cannot share the exact table definition)
Note: cur is the cursor for mysql.

Comment: 'not inserting any rows in my table. Sometimes, the last 10 records in the file are not loading' - is contradictory - can you add the first 20 rows of the csv file as text to the question together with the table definition.

Comment: I meant, sometimes it is inserting the rows except for the last 10 rows.
Sometimes, nothing is getting inserted.
I totally have around 4Million records

Comment: I have the file open in the python file. Closing the file and then using this query worked fine. Thank you.